# Filter Data Table in Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-list, powerapp, datatable, sharepoint-list-filter, powerapps-forms

I'm new to Power Apps and trying to work out something which feels like it should be simple.

I have a screen with a text box (`txtSearch`) and a data table (`tblCatalog`).  The data source for the data table is a SharePoint list (`Catalog`).  I want the table to be filtered based on whether the text in the search box appears in any of the columns (`Title`, `Description`, `Function`) in the table.

I've tried setting the `OnChange` action for `txtSearch` to `Filter(Catalog, Title = txtSearch.Text)`, which is valid; but doesn't affect what's displayed in the table.

I've also tried using:

- `Search(Catalog, txtSearch.Text, Title )`.
- `Search(tblCatalog, txtSearch.Text, Title )`.
- `Filter(tblCatalog, colCatalogTitle = txtSearch.Text)`.

However I get errors such as "has some invalid arguments".  It seems the `Search` function expects a SQL table / doesn't work with other data sources or the Data Table component.

I've spent a while hunting forums / tutorials, but can't find clear guidance on how one would approach tihs when not using a SQL data source; any tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the issue the wrong way around.

I had to amend the Data Table's data source (`Items` property) from `Catalog` to `Filter(Catalog,Title = txtSearch.Text)`